# Error when I try to do a web application in flutter

Tags: flutter, web

this is the error that I get

```html
ralucaraluca@Ralucas-MacBook-Air amuddia % flutter build web
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.0-69.2.beta.

Because amuddia requires SDK version >=2.17.0-182.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in amuddia...                                 
pub get failed (1; Because amuddia requires SDK version >=2.17.0-182.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: It seems you're on the dev channel. Do you mind making sure you're on the stable flutter channel (**flutter channel stable**)? You'd also benefit from being on the latest updated stable channel by running flutter upgrade and try again.

Comment: I did this still same error